# how to remove style added with css las-child

Tags: javascript, html, css

im facing problem to remove the style added with `last-child` attribute of css

**for the first time** i want `last-list` item to be **highlighted**, when a particular element is **clicked** it has to be **highlighted**

```js
$(function(){
   $('.all-list li').click(function(){
      $(this).css('background','red');
      // tried to remove code added with csss, :last-child
      $('.all-list').last().css('background','none');
   });
});
```

```css
ul.all-list{
  list-style:none;
}

ul.all-list li{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px;
  font-size:20px;
}

ul.all-list li:last-child{
  background:red;
}

active-class{
   background:red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="all-list">
   <li>first</li>
   <li>second</li>
   <li>third</li>
   <li>fourth</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sibling to remove color expect clicked one
you can try this method

```
 $(function(){
       $('.all-list li').click(function(){
          $(this).css('background','red');
          $(this).siblings().css('background', 'none');
       });
    });
```

Or

```
 $(function(){
    $('.all-list li').click(function(){
    $(this).css('background','red').siblings().css('background', 'none').end();
       });
     });
```